# How to get multiple files from a django FileField after model form object has been saved

Tags: django, django-forms, django-class-based-views

I have a django ModelForm with an additional field to upload some files.  However, I need the saved model before I can do anything with the files, and I'm not sure where or how to do that.

I'm following the [docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/file-uploads/#uploading-multiple-files).

I either need to get the saved model in the FormView or I need to handle it in the Form:

```
class MessageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Message

    file_field = forms.FileField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}))

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        files = self.cleaned_data.get('files')
        # do stuff with files here...
        # BUT I only get ONE file here, regardless of how many are uploaded with the form.
```

Is there a way for me to get all the files in the Form's save method?

Or, I can get all the files through the view, but how can I get the saved model that I need?  This form is creating a new object, and I need that object before I can do stuff with the files:

```
class FileFieldView(FormView):
    form_class = MessageForm
    template_name = 'upload.html'  # Replace with your template.
    success_url = '...'  # Replace with your URL or reverse().

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        files = request.FILES.getlist('file_field')
        if form.is_valid():
            for f in files:
                ...  # Do something with each file.
                 # BUT how do I get the saved object? I don't think it has been saved at this point anyway?
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if form.is_valid():
        obj = form.save()
        for f in files:
            ...  # Do something with each file.
             # BUT how do I get the saved object? I don't think it has been saved at this point anyway?
```

Comment: could you clarify?

Comment: you now have `obj` which is a `Message` and you can use with your files

Comment: Thanks, I've posted a new question because although this should work, it's not working for me because... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57559590/how-to-get-multiple-files-from-a-django-filefield-after-model-form-object-has-be

Comment: Actually, this doesn't work because it saves the object twice.  Once here, and I assume once again wherever FormView's normally save objects in their normal flow?