# How to get multiple files from a django FileField after model form object has been saved when form.save() does not return object

Tags: django, django-forms, django-class-based-views

I have a django form class that extends [django-postman's WriteForm](https://bitbucket.org/psam/django-postman/src/default/postman/forms.py) (which is a ModelForm) with an additional field to upload some files.

```
from postman.forms import WriteForm

class MyWriteForm(WriteForm):
    file_field = forms.FileField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}))
```

However, I need the saved model before I can do anything with the files.  If I follow the example in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/file-uploads/#uploading-multiple-files), I can extend postman's `FormView` and overwrite the `save()` method:

```
from postman.views import FormView

class MyFormView(FormView):
    form_class = MyWriteForm

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        files = request.FILES.getlist('file_field')
        if form.is_valid():
            for f in files:
                # Do something with each file.
                result = form.save()  # result is a Boolean instead of the object!

            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)
```

However, django-postman WriteForm's `save()` method does not return the object as expected, and instead returns a Boolean.

Is there any other way I can get the ModelForm's object after it is saved? Either through the view or the form?

Comment: `form.instance` is the form's instance, i.e. the `Message` instance. I agree with you that postman is breaking the `ModelForm` save method here and should return the saved instance. It instead returns whether the message was accepted or rejected.

Comment: Note that you should not `form.save()` for every iteration of `for f in files`. Also you code should be in the `form_valid()` method, not in the `post()` method.

Comment: but `form.instance` won't be a saved object yet will it? will it have a pk?  I need the object so I can use it for the primarykey when saving the files to an attachment model.

Comment: Also, why `form_valid()`?    `post()` is how the django docs suggest to do it: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/file-uploads/#uploading-multiple-files

Comment: After the form is saved (`form.save()`) the form’s instance will have a pk.

Comment: Maybe they do it in `post` for clarity, it’s easier to understand what’s going on there. But The FormView already has the code to instantiate and validate the form in the `post` method so it seems more logical to put all custom code in the form_valid method without duplicating the rest. As you like.

Comment: It works. Thanks!  Do you want to post an answer for me to accept?